# Ajuda em Python! Jogo de adivinhação!

Tags: python

Preciso de uma ajuda nesse joguinho. A questão é a seguinte, o jogo eu já fiz e está funcionando perfeitamente, o que eu preciso na verdade é do *loop* com o *While*.

Não consigo achar o erro, enquanto o usuário não acertar o valor eu preciso que o jogo continue até chegar na quinta tentativa, entretanto o meu não está executando o *while* e eu não consigo entender o porquê.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
from random import randint


def acertou():

n = randint(1,11)

x = 0

print(n)


while (x < 5):

    x = x + 1
    y = int(input("Digite um número "))
    if n == y:
        return "Parabéns,você acertou!"
        break
    elif y > n:
        return "Opa,o número que você escolheu é maior que o sorteado!"
    return "Opa,o número que você escolheu é menor que o sorteado!"
```

Comment: Sugestão: arrume a identação do seu código. No Python ela é *fundamental* e precisa estar correta. Quem sabe o código funciona? Outra dica: vc tem uma função (`acertou()`) que vai precisar ser chamada por alguém.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente, você quer que sua função retorne apenas se ele acertar, ou errar mais de 5 vezes, mas nas duas linhas finais:

```
elif y > n:
    return "Opa,o número que você escolheu é maior que o sorteado!"
return "Opa,o número que você escolheu é menor que o sorteado!"
```

voce esta retornando, esta saindo da função retornando o texto. o while não faz nada, pois nao importa qual caminho, o código retorna. ( o break depois do return também nao faz sentido, o return já saiu do código da função inteira )

troque por um print e irá terminar a função apenas se acertar, ou errar mais de 5 vezes.

obs: assumindo que você esteja recebendo dados pelo console.